# Who or what is Agilander in Warcraft III addon "The Almanac of Agilander"?

Tags: warcraft

Who or what is "Agilander" in Warcraft III addon "The Almanac of Agilander"? I would appreciate an etymology of the word, if any, too.

Comment: are you refering to the mod, or is it an ingame item in wc3/FT.

Comment: because afaik its just a fan mod, and so their is no real lore behind it other then whats included in the mod itself.

Comment: I can't even find a solid page for this mod, just some mentions that it was in development.  This question, is in fact top google result for it.  Hoping this isn't an attempt at advertising... doesn't feel like it though.

Comment: @Radhil i doubt it the most recent post about it is back in 2012 lol

Answer (score 1):

**"Agilander" is the name of the land in which the custom map takes place.** The name is apparently a fan creation and does not exist within established WarCraft canon or lore. The intro for the initial map includes the following:

> The land of Agilander is in peril. The king is dead and a mysterious
>   mage is making the most powerful people of Agilander offers of power.
>   All is about to end if his twisted schemes come to life.

The "Almanac of Agilander" presumably refers to some sort of calendar or item of power which is a central plot point of the map series.